# How to execute javascript on a webpage using java

Tags: java, javascript, httpurlconnection

I am establishing a `HttpUrlConnection` with a webpage . Now I have `javascript` snippet that I want to execute on this webpage . How can I do this ?

Comment: javascript gets executed in a browser, so you could use a browser automatisation framework like for example webdriver/selenium

Comment: Do you control the webpage? You cannot execute script directly, as JavaScript is executed client side, but you could code something that listens for incoming connections.

Comment: this is my website . i control it . but i wanted to execute javascript on it as a client .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript              is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
    private static ScriptEngineManager mgr = null;
    private static ScriptEngine engine = null;

    mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    Object eval = engine.eval(s); // s is javascript code
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript needs some kind of Virtual Machine to run in - usually provided by browsers or programms which act like browsers (so called [headless](http://phantomjs.org/) browsers), you have to use some kind of "browsing engine" (so to say) to run the page in. Perhaps [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) may be worth a look.