# JAVA: Execute javascript in loaded URL

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, execute

I'm trying to get the sourcecode of a remote website. The problem is this website execute a javascript in fist time. This javascript create a cookie and then redirect to the final website. If I try to get the sourcecode in a new URL object and read it, the only that I've got is this javascript instead of the sourcecode of final webpage.

My question is how I can load the URL, then execute this javascript and finally get the sourcecode of the final website?

Or even how I can wait some seconds before trying to get the sourcecode avoiding get the javascript that creates de cookie and then redirects to the main website?

Thanks for all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute javascript on a webpage using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716447/how-to-execute-javascript-on-a-webpage-using-java)

Comment: And how are you grabbing the remote data, with AJAX?

Comment: Please add some cod, as we can t guess how u actually achieving it